# String with a variable that can be replaced (php's sprintf equivalent)

Tags: javascript, angular, string

I have a class that looks like below

```
interface IParams: {
  academicYearId: number;
  // Other Params
};
export class myClass() {
  function1() {
    const url = `api/accounts/academic-year/${academicYearId}/financial-plan`;
    // Function 1 Functionality
  }
  function2() {
    const url = `api/accounts/academic-year/${academicYearId}/financial-plan`;
    // Function 2 Functionality
  }
  function3() {
    const url = `api/accounts/academic-year/${academicYearId}/financial-plan`;
    // Function 2 Functionality
  }
}
```

To reduce on the repetition I made url a property

```
interface IParams: {
  academicYearId: number;
  // Other Params
};
export class myClass({academicYearId}: ) {
  url = `api/accounts/academic-year/:id/financial-plan`;
  urlWithId = (academicYearId: number) => this.url.replace(':id', academicYearId )
  function1() {
    const url = this.urlWithId(academicYearId)
    // Function 1 Functionality
  }
  function2() {
    const url = this.urlWithId(academicYearId)
    // Function 2 Functionality
  }
  function3() {
    const url = this.urlWithId(academicYearId)
    // Function 2 Functionality
  }
}
```

The above approach works but am I was wondering if there is a better way I can approach the below two lines other than setting a part of the string to `':id'` and then replace that part with the id value. Something like in [php's sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
url = `api/accounts/academic-year/:id/financial-plan`;
urlWithId = (academicYearId: number) => this.url.replace(':id', academicYearId )
```

Comment: Why not just use an interpolated string, but only define it once like your second example?

Comment: If I use interpolated string then the variable `academicYearId` will be undefined

Comment: You're looking for a format string, not an interpolated string as many seem to be suggesting. JavaScript doesn't have that built in. I'd stick with your current approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**String interpolation**

It's a common approach for doing that like below:

```
urlWithId = (academicYearId) => `api/accounts/academic-year/${academicYearId}/financial-plan`;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: academicYearId is not defined at <anonymous>:1:42`

Comment: @OwenKelvin As can be seen in your code, there is `academicYearId`. I couldn't understand in what scenario error is thrown. Would you explain more?

Comment: True, but that variable is `this.academicYearId` and not `academicYearId`.  But even if you change it to `urlWithId =api/accounts/academic-year/${this.academicYearId}/financial-plan` we get another problem, now the `urlWithId` variable will never change even if we change the value of `this.academicYearId`

Comment: @OwenKelvin The code suggested in my code is just for making  two lines, `url = `api/accounts/academic-year/:id/financial-plan`;
  urlWithId = (academicYearId: number) => this.url.replace(':id', academicYearId )`, shorter. If you like to use it dynamically it's better to put my code in a method and pass `academicYearId` to it for making desire URL in each function.